# Fabricjs unable to set LockScallingX in path

Tags: html, fabricjs

I was making an Arrow in fabric using the path. All thins turns to be fine except that i am unable to lock the scaling of X and Y ie lockScallingX=true when i do this the X scaling is not getting locked. My code is

```
$('#NavArrows').click(function(){
                unbind();
                var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 100 0 M 0 0 L 8 -6 M 0 0 L 8 6 z');
                lockScallingY=true;
                path.setAngle(0).set({ left: 100, top: 100,stroke: 'Black', strokeLineCap: 'round',
                                       hasControls:true,originX: 'center', originY: 'center'});
                lockScallingX=true;
                drawBoard.add(path);});
```

please let me know how to make it work that mine lockScallingX=ture works and my arrow does not get scaled in X direction.

Answer (score 0):

You must write it like this:

```
path.lockScallingX = true;
```

Asign lockScalling property to "path" var defined above...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr5nV/)